# How to write specific raw query in typeorm querybuilder

Tags: mysql, sql, typeorm

When I develop apps, I developed typeorm querybuilder for the aim of getting `attendance` data and `child` data.

When I set following query builder.

```
const Result = await this.attendanceRepository
      .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
      .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
      .select(["attendance.childId","child.class","CONCAT(child.firstName,child.lastName) as'childName'"])
      .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id})
      .getOne()
      return Result;
```

I suffered following errors.

It seems `child.lastName` is not defined.

When I see the sql generated by querybuilder, the following is the cause of problem.

```
CONCAT(`child`.`first_name`,child.lastName)
```

Are there any good way to resolve this ?

Where should I fix ?

```
 code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
api-server    |   errno: 1054,
api-server    |   sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'child.lastName' in 'field list'",
api-server    |   sqlState: '42S22',
api-server    |   index: 0,
api-server    |   sql: "SELECT `attendance`.`child_id` AS `attendance_child_id`, `attendance`.`id` AS `attendance_id`, `child`.`class` AS `child_class`, `child`.`id` AS `child_id`, CONCAT(`child`.`first_name`,child.lastName) as 'childName' FROM `attendances` `attendance` INNER JOIN `children` `child` ON `child`.`id`=`attendance`.`child_id` WHERE ( `attendance`.`id`= '5' ) AND ( `attendance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL )",
api-server    |   query: "SELECT `attendance`.`child_id` AS `attendance_child_id`, `attendance`.`id` AS `attendance_id`, `child`.`class` AS `child_class`, `child`.`id` AS `child_id`, CONCAT(`child`.`first_name`,child.lastName) as 'childName' FROM `attendances` `attendance` INNER JOIN `children` `child` ON `child`.`id`=`attendance`.`child_id` WHERE ( `attendance`.`id`= ? ) AND ( `attendance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL )",
api-server    |   parameters: [ '5' ]
```

If someone has opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: First check your database, do you have this column defined or not?

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from your sql query

```
SELECT `attendance`.`child_id` AS `attendance_child_id`, `attendance`.`id` AS `attendance_id`, `child`.`class` AS `child_class`, `child`.`id` AS `child_id`, CONCAT(`child`.`first_name`,child.lastName) as 'childName'
FROM `attendances` `attendance`
INNER JOIN `children` `child` ON `child`.`id`=`attendance`.`child_id`
WHERE ( `attendance`.`id`= '5' ) AND ( `attendance`.`deleted_at` IS NULL )
```

[postgresql ignores case by default](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS), so `child.lastName` is turned into `child.lastname` which doesn't exist.

What you need to do is put the column name between double quotes: `child.lastName` => `child."lastName"`

Applied to your typeorm code:

```js
const Result = await this.attendanceRepository
      .createQueryBuilder("attendance")
      .innerJoin("attendance.child", "child")
      .select(['"attendance"."childId"', 'child.class', 'CONCAT("child"."firstName", "child"."lastName") as "childName"'])
      .where("attendance.id= :id", { id: id})
      .getOne()
      return Result;
```